# ReactJS using undefined variable even after checking for it not to be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, use-state

`productList` is an array from the redux state, it's the actual array of products. The `cart` is an array of product ids. I set the `productsToRender` to store the products ids and then extract them in the the `ids` variable. In the `useEffect` I am looking for the actual products that are in the cart. The main problem is that my `if statements` do not check properly if the variables are not empty arrays or null or undefined, the code starts to execute the very bottom of the jsx where I am actually using the `products` state variable which is `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`. Therefore throwing an error.

Updated the `useEffect` , the `productList` is `[]` and the if statement does not check it correctly, it prints
`Effect, after if statement [productList] []`

```
const ProductList = ({ productList, cart }) => {

  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(null)
  const productsToRender = cart.products
  const ids = productsToRender.map(p => p.productId)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect [ids]", ids);
    console.log("Effect [productList]", productList);
    if (!productList || productList.length === 0) {
      console.log("Effect, after if statement [productList]", productList);
      let ps = ids.map(id => {
        let product = productList.find(p => p.id === id)
        if (Product) return product
      })
      setProducts(ps)
    }
  }, [productList])

  if (!products || products.length === 0) {
    console.log("Products null or l0", products);
    return <Loading />
  }



... some more jsx


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { productList: state.products };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(ProductList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Things to look for

1. `ps = ps.filter(p =>  p === undefined)` should be `ps = ps.filter(p =>  p !== undefined)`
2. `p.id === id` p.id and id should be of same type.

If this doesn't solve the problem please post the data contained in each of the props.

Comment: check the update

Answer (score 0):

`if (!productList || productList.length === 0)`  should be
`if (!productList || productList.length !== 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement states

`!productsList || productList.length === 0`

which essentially means that the `if` statement code is going to run if your `productsList` array is null **or** has length 0 meaning empty which I reckon is the case with your `productsList` array.

Thus, changing the `if` statement to:

`!productsList || productList.length !== 0` should fix the problem.

Thanks,

Arjis Chakraborty.